# Type.GetProperties() not working

Tags: c#, reflection, getproperties

So I'm trying to retrieve the list of properties generated from a Strings.resx resource.  A **Strings** class is auto-generated from that, and I'm simply trying to get a list of those property names.  Below is some example code of what doesn't work.

```
// Well this works, so I know there is a property there.
var clearly_a_property = Strings.home_cancel;

// Yet none of this works
var nothing = typeof(Strings).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
nothing = typeof(Strings).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
nothing = typeof(Strings).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
nothing = typeof(Strings).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
nothing = typeof(Strings).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
nothing = typeof(Strings).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
nothing = typeof(Strings).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
nothing = typeof(Strings).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
nothing = typeof(Strings).GetProperties();
```

So what gives? The class that's trying to access **Strings** is in the same assembly, so I don't think that's the problem.

Here is a snippet from the auto-generated **Strings** class.

```
/// <summary>
///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
/// </summary>
// This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
// class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
// To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
// with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
internal class Strings {

    //------------------
    // other stuff ...
    //------------------

    internal static string home_cancel {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("home_cancel", resourceCulture);
        }
    }

    //------------------
    // other stuff ...
    //------------------
}
```

Comment: Well, if all your static properties are `internal`, it's only natural that `BindingFlags.Public` doesn't return them.

Comment: Checkout the documentation there is obviously something you are doing incorrectly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `BindingFlags.NonPublic` ?

Comment: You have to at least use both NonPublic and Static flags or'd together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `NonPublic` flag. Of course you need `Static` flag as well, as the property is `static`.

```
var something = typeof(Strings).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
```